# running couple of jars from several versions but with the same name and same classes names

Tags: java, jar, websphere, shared-libraries

I have 5 Shared Libraries on Websphere Application Server.

Each one of them pointing to a different jar with the same name (projectA.jar for ex.).

All jars contains the same classes names (same tree), BUT, the classes code is not identical between jars, as each one of them is a new version of the predecessor.

I'm doing that because I have 5 apps on the app server and every app needs another version of projectA.jar.

Is it ok to place identical jars in the same app server, with the same classes , but not the same code inside?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, as long as you maintain separation between the libraries and applications, and there isn't any direct communication between them.  If you associate each shared library only with the application that needs it, the libraries will get added to the application class loaders, which shouldn't have any visibility to each other unless you're performing some very unorthodox operations.  Each application will load its own copy of the necessary class(es) from its own copy of projectA.jar.  If you have something that makes calls across applications, that does raise a risk of ClassCastExceptions and Verify or LinkageErrors, but if this is just five wholly separate apps, you should be fine.

I would note that if you don't adequately maintain separation (for example, you combine the libraries, or associate more than one with an app, or associate them all with a server-level shared library class loader), then you could be in trouble.  Java can handle multiple classes by the same name, but not within a single class loader - there is no way to actually use the same class from both 1/projectA.jar and 2/projectA.jar if you have them both in a single application class loader or shared library.  Since it sounds like you have a very strong understanding of your dependencies for each application, hopefully that is not a high risk for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Well I'm not using more than one share library per app, BUT I suppose they do all associate with a server-level shared library. because I have only one app server and all the apps are running on this one, including all 5 shared libraries.

Comment: The "server-level shared library class loader" I referred to in my update is a specific thing you'd have to explicitly create - the server configuration (I think in the "class loaders" sub-page) allows you to create a custom class loader on the server that you can associate shared libraries with.  Without something like that, associated with multiple shared libraries, they shouldn't intermingle otherwise.